# Run C++ standalone application in debug mode

Tags: qgis, c++, development, debugging

I write simple C++ standalone application using QGIS. It works and render vector layers from PostgeSQL database.

```
#define CORE_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#define GUI_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)

#include <QString>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

#include <qgsapplication.h>
#include <qgsproviderregistry.h>
#include <qgsmaplayerregistry.h>
#include <qgsvectorlayer.h>
#include <qgsmapcanvas.h>
#include <qgsdatasourceuri.h>
#include <qgssymbolv2.h>
#include <qgssinglesymbolrendererv2.h>
#include <qgscategorizedsymbolrendererv2.h>
#include <qgscoordinatereferencesystem.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class PostGisWidget: public QWidget
{
public:
    PostGisWidget(): QWidget()
    {
        QgsDataSourceURI uri1;
        uri1.setConnection("127.0.0.1", "5432", "gis1", "postgres", "pass", QgsDataSourceURI::SSLdisable);
        uri1.setDataSource("public", "map_points", "the_geom", "");

        QgsDataSourceURI uri2;
        uri2.setConnection("127.0.0.1", "5432", "gis1", "postgres", "pass", QgsDataSourceURI::SSLdisable);
        uri2.setDataSource("public", "map_polygons", "the_geom", "");

        QgsDataSourceURI uri3;
        uri3.setConnection("127.0.0.1", "5432", "gis1", "postgres", "pass", QgsDataSourceURI::SSLdisable);
        uri3.setDataSource("public", "map_polylines", "the_geom", "");

        QgsVectorLayer *layer1 = new QgsVectorLayer(uri1.uri(), "testLayer1", "postgres");
        QgsVectorLayer *layer2 = new QgsVectorLayer(uri2.uri(), "testLayer2", "postgres");
        QgsVectorLayer *layer3 = new QgsVectorLayer(uri3.uri(), "testLayer3", "postgres");
        QgsMapLayerRegistry *registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance();

        registry->addMapLayer(layer1);
        registry->addMapLayer(layer2);
        registry->addMapLayer(layer3);
        this->myLayerSet.append(QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer1));
        this->myLayerSet.append(QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer2));
        this->myLayerSet.append(QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer3));

        QgsMapCanvas *canvas = new QgsMapCanvas();
        canvas->enableAntiAliasing(true);
        canvas->setCrsTransformEnabled(true);
        canvas->setExtent(layer3->extent());
        canvas->setLayerSet(myLayerSet);

        b = new QPushButton("test", this);

        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        layout->addWidget(b);
        layout->addWidget(canvas);
    }
private:
    QList <QgsMapCanvasLayer> myLayerSet;
    QPushButton *b;
};

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MainWindow() : QMainWindow()
    {
        QWidget *w = new QWidget();
        this->setCentralWidget(w);
        PostGisWidget *pW = new PostGisWidget();
        QHBoxLayout *l = new QHBoxLayout(w);
        l->addWidget(pW);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QgsApplication a(argc, argv, true);

    QString myPluginsDir = "D:\\work\\QGIS\\myapp\\qgis\\plugins";
    QString prefixPath = "D:\\work\\QGIS\\myapp\\qgis";

    QgsApplication::setPluginPath( myPluginsDir );
    QgsApplication::setPrefixPath( prefixPath, true);
    QgsApplication::initQgis();

    MainWindow wnd;
    wnd.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I build it in MSVC 2010 in Release mode and it works. But I have "must construct a qapplication before a qpaintdevice" for Debug version. What should I do to debug my QGIS application?

Answer (score 1):

as the compiler says, you have to construct the QApplication first. Instead of:

```
QgsApplication a(argc, argv, true);
```

you have to construct the QAPPLICATION

```
QApplication a(argc, argv, true);
```

I´m pretty shure, thats it.